# d3 zoom into data not image in bar chart or histogram

Tags: d3.js

So I'm able to get mbostock's [Zoomable Area chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254) implemented.  The thing is, I realized (duh) that the data isn't changing on zooming, only the image.  I'd like to be able to zoom into the data, not the image.

Here are some specifics of my dataset.  I receive data when I send a "get_table" request to my data server and I need to tell it how fine to slice up the data and over what range.  Like this:

```
"slice": hours
"from": 1371760800
"to":1380575880
```

and I receive a pile of JSON which I then reformat so that it looks like this:

```
{ "time": 1371760800, "value" : 14 },
{ "time": 1371764400, "value" : 3 },
{ "time": 1371768000, "value" : 14 },
```

etc etc, one entry per hour (3600 seconds).

For what it's worth, I just get the numbers. I add the text and can make it whatever I'd like.

At this point I suppose I have two questions:

1. Since I have a more than a few thousand data points that I need to squeeze into about 1,000 pixels (the screen width) should I use d3.layout.histogram?  I've been experimenting with that and have trouble understanding how I will keep the sense of time in there.  That is to say, ideally the data would be binned - and values summed - into however many bins were necessary to fit into the width.  The Y-axis would show "value" and the X-axis would show the time bins.  Then when the user scrolls into the chart, it would be re-binned into smaller and smaller units.  Which leads me to:
2. If the user zooms in deep enough, I'll need to request finer data from my data server, sliced into minutes.  How would I go about doing that?  I'm thinking that I'd need to send a request out in my zoom function.  Maybe I'll need to sense that they're getting close and request the data a bit before they need it so that there's no UI lag but I could always put up a little "retrieving more data" spinner or something.

Thanks so much ahead of time for any help.  Back to the console for me!

**UPDATE 1**

(To explain the problem a little better.)

I may have up to 100,000 data points, all as the example above:

```
{ "time": 1371760800, "value" : 14 }
```

Assuming horizontal capacity of about 1000 px wide and, a bar width of 4 px and a 1 px margin between bars, I can get 200 bars in the chart.  That means each bar represents about 500 data points (assuming linear time-scale) *if we're showing all the data*.

If, however we zoom in and now the 1000 pixels are showing half the data then we'd show 250 data points per bar.  Of course if we zoomed in enough, we could show 1 data point per bar or even increase the bar size.

Abstractly, what I think I need is a histogram.  I feel like there's gotta be a way within d3's functional programming paradigm to count the "value" but bin on "time". I've tried to play with d3.layout.histogram.bins and while I can bin on "values" to my heart's content, I can't seem to bin on both "time" and "value".  The binning function has to return a threshold of values to bin - I'd like the threshold to look at the "time" value but accumulate the "value".

Comment: Well, I think that part of the answer to #1 is to use a binning function on the histogram.  As per the [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Histogram-Layout#wiki-histogram) the binning function should return a threshold.. I don't know if this will work (tho I'm still wrapping my head around this).

I could always rebin the data myself and just build a plain bar chart but that'll be tricky when zooming in.  Maybe I could use SVG zooming (transform translate) for the animation and when they're done zooming, recalculate and redraw the bar chart.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I'm familiar with that example and while I'm thinking of going down that route, I don't think that'll do it because I'm under the impression that they're showing all the data - if you brush the entire smaller graph you'll see all the data in the upper graph.

I have too much data to do that.  I'd need the upper graph to be zoomed into the data, not just a different SVG of the same data.

Comment: You could easily restrict how much you could select in the lower graph. I'm just not sure what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff.. I've edited the question to (hopefully) better express what I'm looking for...

Comment: D3's histogram layout doesn't allow you what you want to do, so you would have to implement that functionality yourself.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to get things done with d3.nest and nest.rollup working on parts of each datum's date field... hmmm.  I find it hard to believe that it's this tricky to summarize data in d3.

Comment: If you found a solution to this problem I am very interested!

Comment: Yep, @PepijnvanDiepen I did get it all working real nice. You could flick the mouse wheel and zoom into the data. Only trick was that it was 3 years ago and I don't remember what I did off the top of my head. One day when my kiddos are grown I'll look it up :-)

What I _do_ know is that I did what LarsKotthoff suggested and implemented it myself. Wasn't too algorithmic.. just some basic math, if I recall correctly.