# d3 convert x axis from array indices to dates

Tags: d3.js

I have a data that is an array of values, like this:

```
[244, 13, 24, 0, 18, 24, 3, 4, ... ]
```

While array indices are simply integers, in this data they represent a range of dates such that the 0th index represents, say, `06/04/2013` and the last index represents `09/30/2013` although they're actually in seconds since 1970, so `1370378409` and `1380575923` would be more precise.

I would like my x-axis to show the dates that the array indices represent.  So that the ticks would look like dates: `Mon 08`, `Tue 09` and so on.  As the data will change, I cannot know what the ticks should be ahead of time.. I'm hoping they can be calculated from the endpoints which I do know.

Theoretically, I'm thinking that I can convert from the domain of the x-axis (the chart's width) to the date range represented in the array.  Something like this (but this didn't work in this formulation):

```
var xAsTime = d3.time.scale()
                 .domain([0, width])
                 .range([startDate, endDate])
```

which should nicely translate from integers to dates.

Comment: As Jonah pointed out, there's a time axis in D3, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/robdodson/KWRxW/) for an example. You also should give your dates explicitly in the data, this will make working with them easier.

Comment: Yes I get that if I actually had dates, I could use the d3.time.scale (and have used it successfully before) but as per my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155844/d3-zoom-into-data-not-image-in-bar-chart-or-histogram) I'm zoomed out in the data and could only estimate what each data point represents - it's a range of dates that changes.

Comment: Ok, but you have some mapping from these values to dates, right? So you could get all the dates for a specific array that way.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Also, I don't really have a mapping of those values to dates.  The atomic data is `"timeInSeconds : "value"` (one per hour or minute) which, as you mentioned in that other question, I need to aggregate myself.  So now I have the data aggregated into as many bars (bins) as will fit in the width.  I could come up with a date that represents the bin but I figured that with d3's axis function I could do it better (somehow).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the code you've posted didn't work?

Comment: I just got it to work.  I'm writing up an answer..

Answer (score 0):

d3 has a built in time scale specifically for this purpose:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales

Comment: See my comment to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The x function usually scales from your data domain to the range needed which is often the width of your chart.  This is how you'll find things in many examples.

Usually to create axes, you pass to d3.svg.axis() your x function.  However, the main job of the x function is often to create, in my case, the bars of a bar chart.

My own x function that I'm using in this bar chart:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, data.length])
            .rangeRound([0, width]);
```

Here's one from [MBostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7441121):

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
```

And another with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robdodson/KWRxW/):

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([new Date(data[0].date),
                    d3.time.day.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 1)])
            .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
```

Using the power and simplicity of d3 scales, I was able to solve this problem by converting from array indices to dates with a separate x function, xAsTime, like so:

```
var xAsTime = d3.time.scale()
                  .domain([this.start * 1000, this.end * 1000])
                  .range([0, width])

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xAsTime)
                .tickSize(-height)
                .tickPadding(3);
```

As per my question, the only change was to switch the domain and ranges.  While I unsure of the details, it seems like the domain of the scale is what is displayed as ticks.